# How to design a Table with a fixed header during printing without cutting the header?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, printing-web-page

I had this **Table**, I want when **I print the table**, should print with a fixed header on each paper, and it's doing that, but the headers does not start on the **top** of the paper, *something going wrong*

```
<table id="TableDtl" class="tableClass  cellWithborder"
    style="width:100%;overflow:scroll; font-weight:bold; border: 1px solid Black;">
    <thead>
        <th style="height:80px; font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">
            <header0>ID</header0>
        </th>
        <th style="height:80px; font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">
            <header1>NAME</header1>
        </th>
        <th style="height:80px; font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">
            <header2>Quantity</header2>
        </th>
        <th style="height:80px; font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">
            <header3>Per</header3>
        </th>
        <th style="height:80px; font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">
            <header4>Price</header4>
        </th>
        <th style="height:80px; font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">
            <header5>Free</header5>
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">100-933-03</td>
            <td style=" font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;width:30%">Just For Test</td>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">4</td>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">Test</td>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">444</td>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">6666</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

**I search about it a lot** and I try something like this style:

```
<style>

    @media print {
        @page{
            margin:1em;
        }

        table { 
            page-break-after:auto;
            border-collapse:collapse;
        }
        tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
        td    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
        thead { 
            display:table-header-group;
        }
        tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
    }

</style>
```

**It didn't work at all**, and I try playing with (`page-break-before`, `page-break-after`, `page-break-inside`) and also nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
    @media print{ input {display:none} };
</style>

<input type=button value="print" onclick=javascript:window.print()> 
<table id="TableDtl" class="tableClass  cellWithborder"
    style="width:100%;overflow:scroll; font-weight:bold; border: 1px solid Black;" >
    <thead>
        <th style="height:80px; font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">
            <header0>ID</header0>
        </th>
        <th style="height:80px; font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">
            <header1>NAME</header1>
        </th>
        <th style="height:80px; font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">
            <header2>Quantity</header2>
        </th>
        <th style="height:80px; font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">
            <header3>Per</header3>
        </th>
        <th style="height:80px; font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">
            <header4>Price</header4>
        </th>
        <th style="height:80px; font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">
            <header5>Free</header5>
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">100-933-03</td>
            <td style=" font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;width:30%">Just For Test</td>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">4</td>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">Test</td>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">444</td>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">6666</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">100-933-03</td>
            <td style=" font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;width:30%">Just For Test</td>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">4</td>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">Test</td>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">444</td>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">6666</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">100-933-03</td>
            <td style=" font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;width:30%">Just For Test</td>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">4</td>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">Test</td>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">444</td>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">6666</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">100-933-03</td>
            <td style=" font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;width:30%">Just For Test</td>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">4</td>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">Test</td>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">444</td>
            <td style="font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">6666</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have fixed header display issue on print's every page. You need to add multiple TR inside TBODY and check the result. If any issue found then let me know

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `display` of `thead`: `table-header-group`

```
thead { 
    display: table-header-group
}
```

**Demo:**

```css
table { 
    border-collapse:collapse;
    height: 400px;
}
td, th {
   text-align: center;
   padding: 8px;
}
table, td, th {
   border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
@media print {
    @page{
        margin:1em;
    }

    table { 
        page-break-after:auto;
    }

    td, th {
        padding: 8px;
    }
    tr { 
     page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto
    }
    td { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
    thead { 
        display:table-header-group;      /* <== here */
    }
    tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="window.print()">
<br />
<br />

<table>
    <thead>
        <th style="height:80px; font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">
            <header0>ID</header0>
        </th>
        <th style="height:80px; font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">
            <header1>NAME</header1>
        </th>
        <th style="height:80px; font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">
            <header2>Quantity</header2>
        </th>
        <th style="height:80px; font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">
            <header3>Per</header3>
        </th>
        <th style="height:80px; font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">
            <header4>Price</header4>
        </th>
        <th style="height:80px; font-size:x-large;font-weight:bold;">
            <header5>Free</header5>
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>100-933-03</td>
            <td>Just For Test</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>444</td>
            <td>6666</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>100-933-03</td>
            <td>Just For Test</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>444</td>
            <td>6666</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>100-933-03</td>
            <td>Just For Test</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>444</td>
            <td>6666</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>100-933-03</td>
            <td>Just For Test</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>444</td>
            <td>6666</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>100-933-03</td>
            <td>Just For Test</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>444</td>
            <td>6666</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>100-933-03</td>
            <td>Just For Test</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>444</td>
            <td>6666</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>100-933-03</td>
            <td>Just For Test</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>444</td>
            <td>6666</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>100-933-03</td>
            <td>Just For Test</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>444</td>
            <td>6666</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>100-933-03</td>
            <td>Just For Test</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>444</td>
            <td>6666</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>100-933-03</td>
            <td>Just For Test</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>444</td>
            <td>6666</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>100-933-03</td>
            <td>Just For Test</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>444</td>
            <td>6666</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>100-933-03</td>
            <td>Just For Test</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>444</td>
            <td>6666</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>100-933-03</td>
            <td>Just For Test</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>444</td>
            <td>6666</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>100-933-03</td>
            <td>Just For Test</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>444</td>
            <td>6666</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>100-933-03</td>
            <td>Just For Test</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>444</td>
            <td>6666</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>100-933-03</td>
            <td>Just For Test</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Test</td>
            <td>444</td>
            <td>6666</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```